# What's the result of the SQL statement "SELECT DATEADD(s,1234567890, '19700101')"?

Tags: sql, date, time, epoch

For some reason, my SQL installation isn't working :)

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,1234567890, '19700101')
```

Maybe [this site](http://coolepochcountdown.com/) would help (link from [Moose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19032/moose)).

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, is NOT a question, and does not belong here. Sorry, but you should go to digg with this.

Comment: Grammatically, it is a question and it does have to do with programming, even if somewhat mixed with numerology.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Total awesomeness!

Comment: Robin, I award you the correct answer for this question for being so astute :)  I couldn't believe this when I saw it.  Geeks the world over should have a second's silence.

Comment: Question will be closed once people actually realise what you're on about unfortunately.

Comment: Robin -- I'll give you the answer tomorrow just to lure more people to this question in the meantime.  Shame that SO doesn't show the date that the question is asked, just how long ago.

Comment: I don't see why it should be closed.  It's a real question about programming.

Comment: How about you get a life and ask some real programming question instead of some trivia that's been around the nets for weeks.

Comment: Thank you DV for your feedback.  Very valuable.

Answer (score 3):

I get this:

```
2009-02-13 23:31:30.000
```

Comment: Interesting.  That looks familiar... :)

Answer (score 2):

[`DATE_ADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) (not `DATEADD`) has just two arguments.

Comment: I guess it depends upon which SQL you use.  At any rate, the result quoted above looks familiar today for some reason...

Comment: Haha, sorry about that. MyMISTAKE :)